# Attaching IntelliJ IDEA debugger to Fitnesse

Tags: intellij-idea, fitnesse

At my work we use FitNesse extensively. I am trying to determine whether a customized build of Fitnesse will better serve our needs, so I'm trying to set up a development environme1nt that allows me to work on and debug the Fitnesse source. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.7, and JDK 1.7. I have it building, and I can run it using the supplied ant task, but I am having trouble with debugging.

I found this guide, which I think does what I need:
http://www.discernment-solutions.com/?p=101

But I can't get it to work. When I try to attach the debugger I get a message saying "unable to open debugger port"

I'm not really a Java guy, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. One thing I'm confused about is that the guide seems to be suggesting that when I start a test it will start a new Java process which I can attach to. But in order to even start the test or make the edits to it, I must already be running a Java process. Does this matter?

Answer (score 1):

I have a working solution now, although it is not based on the REMOTE_DEBUG_COMMAND method. I just added these lines to the "run" ant task:

```
<jvmarg value="-Xdebug" />
<jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8100" />
```

I'm still not sure how the other way was supposed to work, but this way is more convenient for what I'm doing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a different port? Chances are the port you tried is already being used by some other application.

java -Xdebug 
     -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 
     -cp %p %m

(try something other than 8000)